# Real World Examples of Sinusoidal and Logistic Functions (and Regression)?

Tags: regression

Anyone ever use a real world example (or data) of either:
1) Sinusoidal Regression
2) Logistic/Log Regression

This can alternatively be answered by identifying any real world **functions** that are: 
1) Sinusoidal 
2) Logistic/Log Regression

Anything beyond the dry textbook examples of temperature patterns or population growth?
Thanks!